Hilt Inject Activity for BiometricPrompt
I' m using Hilt for DI and inside a class I need the Activity in order to show the biometric prompt.
class BiometricPromptManagerImpl(
    private val activity: AppCompatActivity
) : BiometricPromptManager {

    fun showBiometricPrompt(...) {
        val prompt = BiometricPrompt(
            activity,
            ...
        )
    }

}

With this approach when I call prompt.authenticate() I get an exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Your activity is not yet attached to the Application instance. You can't request ViewModel before onCreate call.
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.getViewModelStore(ComponentActivity.kt:543)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.<init>(ViewModelProvider.android.kt:66)
    at androidx.biometric.BiometricPrompt.getViewModel(BiometricPrompt.java:1027)
    at androidx.biometric.BiometricPrompt.<init>(BiometricPrompt.java:770)
    at BiometricPromptManagerImpl.showBiometricPrompt(BiometricPromptManagerImpl.kt:28)
    at BiometricManagerImpl.setBiometricEnabled(BiometricManagerImpl.kt:40)
    at SecuritySettingsViewModel$setBiometricEnabled$1.invokeSuspend(SecuritySettingsViewModel.kt:61)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:367)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:30)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable$default(Cancellable.kt:25)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:110)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:126)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch(Builders.common.kt:56)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch(Unknown Source:1)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch$default(Builders.common.kt:47)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch$default(Unknown Source:1)
    at SecuritySettingsViewModel.setBiometricEnabled(SecuritySettingsViewModel.kt:58)
    at SecuritySettingsKt.SecuritySettings$lambda$4$lambda$3(SecuritySettings.kt:42)
    at SecuritySettingsKt.$r8$lambda$Vs8cN5zb-pHpMQoWh8tjFWFDDy4(Unknown Source:0)
    at SecuritySettingsKt$$ExternalSyntheticLambda6.invoke(D8$$SyntheticClass:0)
    at SecuritySettingsKt.BiometricSwitch$lambda$12$lambda$11$lambda$10(SecuritySettings.kt:111)
    at SecuritySettingsKt.$r8$lambda$9J-jxcYvOybEe49aXaa33x9FGcA(Unknown Source:0)
    at SecuritySettingsKt$$ExternalSyntheticLambda10.invoke(D8$$SyntheticClass:0)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.selection.ToggleableNode$1.invoke(Toggleable.kt:229)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.selection.ToggleableNode$1.invoke(Toggleable.kt:229)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.ClickableNode$clickPointerInput$3.invoke-k-4lQ0M(Clickable.kt:639)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.ClickableNode$clickPointerInput$3.invoke(Clickable.kt:633)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.TapGestureDetectorKt$detectTapAndPress$2$1.invokeSuspend(TapGestureDetector.kt:255)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.resume(DispatchedTask.kt:179)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.dispatch(DispatchedTask.kt:168)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.dispatchResume(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:474)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:508)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl$default(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:497)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeWith(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:368)
    at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.SuspendingPointerInputModifierNodeImpl$PointerEventHandlerCoroutine.offerPointerEvent(SuspendingPointerInputFilter.kt:719)
    at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.SuspendingPointerInputModifierNodeImpl.dispatchPointerEvent(SuspendingPointerInputFilter.kt:598)
    at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.SuspendingPointerInputModifierNodeImpl.onPointerEvent-H0pRuoY(SuspendingPointerInputFilter.kt:620)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.AbstractClickableNode.onPointerEvent-H0pRuoY(Clickable.kt:1044)
    at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.Node.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:387)
    at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.Node.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:373)
    at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.NodeParent.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:229)
    at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.HitPathTracker.dispatchChanges(HitPathTracker.kt:144)
    at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.PointerInputEventProcessor.process-BIzXfog(PointerInputEventProcessor.kt:120)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.sendMotionEvent-8iAsVTc(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1994)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.handleMotionEvent-8iAsVTc(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1945)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.dispatchTouchEvent(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1829)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3122)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2803)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3122)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2803)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3122)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2803)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3122)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2803)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3122)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2803)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3122)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2803)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3122)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2803)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:458)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1981)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:4533)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:416)
    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:16737)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7947)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:7710)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:7106)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:7163)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:7129)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:7295)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:7137)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:7352)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:7110)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:7163)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:7129)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:7137)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:7110)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:10214)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:10165)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:10134)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:10356)
    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:295)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:346)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:189)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:317)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8705)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:580)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:886)

A possible solution would be to pass the activity from the composable but I have some concern about clean architecture principles.
What is the best solution to show the biometric prompt?
Use
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object MyModule { 
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideBiometricPromptManager(
        activity: MainActivity
    ): BiometricPromptManager {
        return BiometricPromptManagerImpl(activity)
    }
}



What is the best solution to show the biometric prompt?

Display it directly from your composable. See, for example:

BiometricPrompt with Jetpack Compose
https://blog.shipbook.io/biometric-authentication
https://medium.com/@munbonecci/how-to-add-biometrics-in-jetpack-compose-d6c349555b64
https://dev.to/canopassoftware/how-to-implement-biometric-authentication-with-jetpack-compose-and-aes-encryption-4e72
https://medium.com/@rzmeneghelo/biometric-authentication-in-jetpack-compose-e34875518b88
https://proandroiddev.com/biometric-authorization-in-compose-multiplatform-app-a00e0fa64640

and many other examples available on the Internet.

I have some concern about clean architecture principles

Not everything is appropriate for dependency inversion. Android is an imperfect match for clean architecture. IMHO, focus on it for "behind the UI" concerns like viewmodels, use cases, repositories, data sources, etc.
